# C# project : How to add an executable to the project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have a VS2008 C# project that use a 3rd party executable. What is the best way to add this executable to the project , such that it will be released when publishing the project? As a resource?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use it's public API, add it as a reference. If you don't, it doesn't really matter. You can just add it to you project by dragging it into the solution explorer and set it's properties in the properties window. There you can select to publish it with the rest of the assemblies.